# Table row on top of columns

Tags: html, html-email

The text I have on top in the table row is somehow affected by the second column below it..cant seem to have it take up the entire width of the table.

http://jsfiddle.net/PmWBw/2/

Sorry I know I am the only one still working in tables. HTML emails still exist.

```
 <table width="800" class="bodyContent" style="border: 1px solid #b8b7b7;margin-bottom: 20px;">

            <table> 
                 <tr style="width: 800px;">TEST TEXT TEST TEXT TEST TEXT TEST TEXT TEST TEXT TEST TEXT</tr>
            </table>


            <td valign="top" width="260" class="leftColumnContent">

                <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr mc:repeatable>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <img src="http://www.homeplan.com/newsletter/images/top_left.png" mc:label="image" mc:edit="tiwc300_image00" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>


            <td valign="top" width="260" class="rightColumnContent">

                <!-- // Begin Module: Top Image with Content \\ -->
                <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr mc:repeatable>

                        <td valign="top">

                            <img src="http://www.homeplan.com/newsletter/images/top_right.png" mc:label="image" mc:edit="tiwc300_image01" />

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>  
            </td>                  
</table>
```

Comment: It seems you have td and tr interchanged in your parent table. But the tables inside it have the correct tr/td. this is how it looks like when fixed, but this may not be your desired layout. http://jsfiddle.net/75rh5/

Comment: humph. the text still breaks in the middle...

Comment: you just readjust the width. it's set to 600px when i copied your jsfiddle, and it seems you readjusted to 800px.

Comment: I was just seeing if 600 was too short. But its strange how it breaks way before it reaches 600.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, your first row consists of a td inside a tr that's inside ANOTHER td.  If nothing else, that should probably be addressed.

Also, a bit unrelated to you original question, but it seems a bit redundant to have tables inside of your cells, when I'm not seeing any real benefit or function gained by the added code.  You're styling your inner tables with the same things you can be applying to either the td or the image itself.  At least in this particular application.
Just a thought.


**UPDATED:**

```
<table width="600" class="bodyContent" style="border: 1px solid #b8b7b7;margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <table>
                <tr style="width: 600px;">
                    <td>TEST TEXT TEST TEXT TEST TEXT TEST TEXT TEST TEXT TEST TEXT</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td valign="top" width="260" class="leftColumnContent">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr mc:repeatable>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <img src="http://www.homeplan.com/newsletter/images/top_left.png" mc:label="image" mc:edit="tiwc300_image00" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>

        <td valign="top" width="260" class="rightColumnContent">
            <!-- // Begin Module: Top Image with Content \\ -->
            <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr mc:repeatable>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <img src="http://www.homeplan.com/newsletter/images/top_right.png" mc:label="image" mc:edit="tiwc300_image01" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: removed the td within the td. But for some reason the columns now don't stack side by side.

Comment: You now have a table->table->tr relationship.  You need to have a table->tr->td->table->tr->td.  A table is made up of a tr (row), which then contains td's (columns).  You have to stick with that structure or you'll break it.  A table can't be within the table unless it's within a td, which is in turn within a tr, which is then within a table.

Comment: Thanks Mike. But now the columns dont stack side by side...http://jsfiddle.net/PmWBw/3/

Comment: They should.  They may not in jsfiddle without hitting Run once or twice, but as far as the code you have, you should get 3 columns.  Try saving it as an html file and open it up in a browser.

Comment: Oh this shows three columns of text. Im sorry I must have been unclear. I am trying to make one column the width of the table (600px)

Comment: Like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/PmWBw/5/  
You would need to make the top one its own row by enclosing it in its own tr's, then add a "colspan=2" to the top cell/td since it will be spanning two columns.  You'll need to adjust widths and things but that fiddle should at least give you the general layout.

Comment: Glad to help.  I've updated my original answer with some updated code, including some updated widths (which you'll still want to comb over and refine).  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can not have the code looking like this:`<td><tr><td>asdf</td></tr></td>`. It the `<tr>` needs to be wrapped by `<table>`.